# How do I set the name of a Label in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a name to a label so I can find it using the Content.FindByName<>() method

as far as I can tell the Xamarin.Forms.Label() class doesn't have a Name property

Here is my page class

```
public class HelloWordCodePage : ContentPage
{
    public Label HelloWorldLabel;

    public HelloWordCodePage()
    {
        HelloWorldLabel = new Label{Text = "Hello World", };
        ConstructView();
    }

    public void ConstructView()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                HelloWorldLabel
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're making it in code why not just keep the reference somehow?

Answer (score 16):

If you define your label in Xaml, you can use this syntex:

```
<Label x:Name="YourLableName" Text="A simple Label" />
```

And then access it in the code behind like this

```
YourLableName.Text = "bla bla"
```

However, if you don't use Xaml, and all your page definition is found in the code behind, you should keep a reference to that label in order to access it instead of finding it using `Content.FindByName<>()` as @Sten Petrov commented

Answer (score 1):

I believe the name is only meant to be used when creating the element in XAML. If you look at the inheritance you will find [Element](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AXamarin.Forms.Element) at the bottom and it implements INameScope explicitly. You cannot cast Label to INameScope as that is an internal interface:

```
namespace Xamarin.Forms
{
    internal interface INameScope
    {
        object FindByName(string name);

        void RegisterName(string name, object scopedElement);

        void UnregisterName(string name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Name is assigned at the **Render** processing stage.  There is no need to know the rendered name at this time as you are working on a cross-platform **ContentPage**.

There is a *GUID*, but like you say there is no *ID*.  You wouldn't in my opinion ever want to get a platform-specific ID for the generated control at this high a level of page design.  If you do then perhaps you need to create a platform-specific **PageRenderer** instead?

When you start to write *CustomRenderers* and create platform specific controls you can then assign IDs if you so wish any custom control platform specific implementations you want.

Remember on the current **ContentPage** - you have a *class-scoped* object reference already to your label named **HelloWorldLabel**, that you can use to change its appearance etc on the page when in execution.

Answer (score 1):

StyleId

Use the StyleId property to identify individual elements in your application
for identification in ui testing and in theme engines.

Comment: This should be the right answer. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.styleid?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: This doesn't work with the `Content.FindByName<>()` method the OP mentions. At least it doesn't now.

Answer (score 1):

As IdoT says, if you define an object at runtime, you need to keep a reference to that in order to access it as it is not possible to assign a name.
I use a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Guid, String> ControlsDictionary = new Dictionary<Guid, string>();
```

Then when I create an object:

```
Button bt = new Button {Text="Yay!"};

        bt.Clicked += OnButtonClicked;
        StackLayout.Children.Add(bt);

        ControlsDictionary.Add(bt.Id, "myname");
```

In the Click event handler I can identify the sender "name":

```
async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        String NameofButton = ControlsDictionary[btn.Id];

    }
```

also you can obtain the Id from the "name":

```
Guid IdfromName = ControlsDictionary.First(x => x.Value == "myname").Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is bit late but was working through some of xamarin forms issues and remembered I did some thing similar in past, before I started implementing MVVM. This is how I used `Content.FindByName<>()` is a rough example below.

**XAML**

```
<BoxView Color="Gray" HeightRequest="2"  HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
<Label x:Name="DoorMaterial" x:Uid="41" Text="Door Material"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Door_Material" x:Name="RB_99" Value="99" ClassId="41"  CheckedChanged="RB_CheckedChanged" Content="Wood" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Material" x:Name="RB_100" Value="100" ClassId="41"  CheckedChanged="RB_CheckedChanged" Content="Steel" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Material" x:Name="RB_101" Value="101" ClassId="41"  CheckedChanged="RB_CheckedChanged" Content="Upvc" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Material" x:Name="RB_102" Value="102" ClassId="41"  CheckedChanged="RB_CheckedChanged" Content="Composite" ></RadioButton>
```

**C#**

```
private void SetPageFields(ICollection<DoorTemplateAnswerRecordModel> answerRecordModelsList)
{
    string RadioButtonName = "RB_";

    foreach (var answerRecordModel in answerRecordModelsList)
    {
        var answerId = answerRecordModel.AnswerId.ToString();
        var combinedWithId = RadioButtonName + answerId;

        var getCheckBox = Content.FindByName<RadioButton>(combinedWithId);

        if (getCheckBox != null)
        {                   
            getCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```